# Ruby on Rails 3 nested routes: wrong action route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-routes

I have two models: team and project

routes.rb

```
resources :teams do
  resource :projects
end
```

And two questions!

**1-** According to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html, I expect to get teams/:team_id/projects/:id path. However, this is not the case.

rake routes

```
         team_projects POST     /teams/:team_id/projects(.:format)      projects#create
     new_team_projects GET      /teams/:team_id/projects/new(.:format)  projects#new
    edit_team_projects GET      /teams/:team_id/projects/edit(.:format) projects#edit
                       GET      /teams/:team_id/projects(.:format)      projects#show
                       PUT      /teams/:team_id/projects(.:format)      projects#update
                       DELETE   /teams/:team_id/projects(.:format)      projects#destroy
```

so I had to name route to get it working

```
  match 'teams/:team_id/projects/:id' => 'projects#show', :via => [:get], :as => :show_project
```

so how can take advantage of rails helper methods instead of naming them?

---

**2-**  In project show action view, the debugger throws these parameters for me:

```
action: show
controller: projects
team_id: '1'
```

which is fine. but when I click on "new_team_projects_path" url, it redirects me to the same view and the debugger throws these parameters:

```
controller: projects
action: show
team_id: '1'
id: new
```

It doesn't redirect me to the new action, but it took "new" as an ID! why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to use

   ```
   resources :teams do
     resources :projects
   end
   ```

   Note the plural! `resource` produces a singular route without id.
2. won't be relevant anymore with the first fix.

Comment: SERIOUSLY??! and I looked for a solutions for hours. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Well, it's in the guide ;) But I know that feeling.

Comment: This was causing me the issue where /magazine/:id/ads would route to #show instead of #index

Comment: It's incredible, how a simple character can harm a person's metal health.